# Linking from a form submit (HTML)

Tags: html

I'm currently attempting to make a form both submit data to my mercury server and link to the next part of the form, is this possible?

```
     <p><input type="submit" value="Register" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

These are my submit and reset button(pretty standard), they have no problem submitting the data to my server however I can't seem to make it link to the next form purchase.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to send the form and load a new page at the same time. It will cause errors since only the fastest will succeed and the other one will fail.

When you submit a form the browser performs a request to the action in the form tag. A common way of achieving what you want is to reply with a redirect to purchase.html if the registration was successful. If it was not, then redirect to the previous page and show an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send the form -> set a redirect on the form verification page. You cannot do these things at once.